# Xcode - build string from multiple sources

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Hi just starting to learn this language, more of a javascript/PHP guy...

I can't seem to figure out the proper syntax and after searching the internets for a straight answer or explanation I decided to bother you SOF community:

This works as I want it to work:

```
    self.displaysTheStack.text = [self.displaysTheStack.text stringByAppendingString:@" "];
    self.displaysTheStack.text = [self.displaysTheStack.text stringByAppendingString:operation];
    self.displaysTheStack.text = [self.displaysTheStack.text stringByAppendingString:@" "];
```

I wanted to know if I could do the same thing in less lines something like:

```
NSString *displayTheArrayText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" ",operation,@" "];

self.displaysTheStack.text = [self.displaysTheStack.text stringByAppendingString:displayTheArrayText];
```

When I do it this way I get the Two @" " (spaces) but "operation" doesn't show up:  why and how do I write the latter command properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stringWithFormat:` uses [C-style formats](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1) similar to those used by [printf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html)

you probably want something like that:

```
NSString *displayTheArrayText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ ",operation];
```

have a look at [Formatting String Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943)

Comment: Not married to the stringWithFormat is it the best way to concatenate  static and variable strings?  What if I had multiple sources operation, dperation and cperation...

Comment: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ %@ %@ %@ %@ ",operation, op1, op2, op3, op4];` Or use a `NSMutableString` like Rob used it in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.displaysTheStack.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ ", self.displaysTheStack.text, operation];
```

Alternately:

```
NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString stringWithString:self.displaysTheStack.text];
[string appendFormat:@" %@ ", operation];
self.displaysTheStack.text = string;
```

Comment: This works too, thanks helps me understand, too bad we can't flag 2 answers,  I upvoted anyhow...thanks again...